# Como versionar projeto Spring Boot?

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, github, maven

Estou fazendo um curso de Spring Boot mas acredito que estou versionando de forma incorreta, pois não consigo rodar a aplicação após dar um `git clone`.

Estou acostumado com o versionamento do Angular e Node, pois é só dar um `npm install` que já ta tudo certo. Estou iniciando no mundo Maven agora e gostaria de saber o que pode ir pro `.gitignore` e como rodar normalmente a aplicação em outro PC.

Link do repositório: https://github.com/gabrielgambarra/curso-spring-boot

Comment: seu projeto está ok, acabei de clonar e importar ele com sucesso, o processo de abrir o projeto muda de IDE para IDE, qual você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando o STS. Achei tutoriais que falavam pra importar como um projeto maven existente. Mas não rola. Poderia responder com o passo-a-passo que tu fez para abrir ele? Obrigado!

Comment: Postei como importar na resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Importar o projeto no STS:

- Package Explore em uma parte vazia clicar com o botão direito no `Import...`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Vai abrir uma janela, nela você abre a opção `Maven` e seleciona `Existing Maven Projects` e clica em `Next`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Clica em `Browse...` para escolher a pasta onde tem o projeto e clica em `Selecionar pasta`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O Sts vai percorer a pasta procurando pelos projetos, vai aparecer o seu conforme o print.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Clicar me `Finish`, O sts vai baixar as dependências que tem no pom.xml e o seu projeto vai aparecer o package explorer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Genial, funcionou kkk pelo menos aqui na minha máquina foi. Vou testar novamente na máquina que tive esse problema. Pelo menos agora sei a forma certa de fazer. Muito obrigado!